# CSS3 rotateY doesn't behave the same in Safari and Chrome

Tags: html, css

I'm experiencing something pretty weird and tricky with WebKit. I'm playing around with a CSS animation, where a div is rotating around the Y axe, while another div in background is doing nothing. Problem is that, in Safari, the div that is rotating gets cut by the first div, instead of rotating on top of it.

It's a little bit hard to explain, so here's a JSfiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/HMF6f/

Some mentioned that adding a 3d translation could fix it (like below), but in the case of a complex animation, this totally changes the visual look, and that's not working for me.

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 100px) rotateY(-50deg);
```

I like how Chrome behaves with this, and I'd like to have a same behavior. Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I have the same issue